# Zend getting database record false

Tags: php, sql, database, zend-framework

I have a link http://mywebsite.com/referral/dafa60b2b96c366e165be58649755742

With a parameter dafa60b2b96c366e165be58649755742

Was try to get that parameter to connect to database to get that user information, but it end up getting no object: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in line.....

here's my code:

application.ini:

> resources.router.routes.referralSelectProduct.route = "/referral/:url"
>   resources.router.routes.referralSelectProduct.defaults.controller = Index
>   resources.router.routes.referralSelectProduct.defaults.action = referral-select-product
>   resources.router.routes.referralSelectProduct.reqs.url = "[0-9a-zA-Z]+"

controller:

```
public function referralSelectProductAction()
{
    $referral_url = $this->getRequest()->getParam('url');
    $user = $this->_helper->model('Users')->fetchRowByFields(array('url' => $referral_url));

    setcookie('referral_url', $referral_url, time() + 3600*24*30, '/');
}
```

model:

```
    class Application_Model_DbTable_Users extends Sayka_Db_Table_Abstract{
protected $_rowClass = 'Application_Model_DbTable_Row_User';protected $_name = 'users';}
```

view:

```
<div id="content_bottom" class="content"><br/>
<h1>Select the product to refer your friend <span class="colorset_orange"><?php echo $this->user()->first_name; ?></span>.</h1>
<div><a class="refer_submit" href="?email=<?php echo $this->user()->email ?>&first_name=<?php echo $this->user()->first_name; ?>&last_name=<?php echo $this->user()->last_name; ?>" id="btn_free_download">Free Download</a></div>
<div><a class="refer_submit" href="#" id="btn_buy_now">Buy Now</a></div>
```

My view end up getting no object of that user in the database.

Comment: Can you explicitly tell us what line of code it is that you are getting the error from and show contextual code up to where you get that error?  That error is pretty clear in that on that line of code you are trying to make an operation on an object, but the variable you think holds an object does not.

Comment: its actually on the view when i echo $this->user()-> all these echo give a error. It doesn't get the database record of that user

Comment: You are not even showing any lines of code that make a call to `$this->user()`.  Obviously the `user` object is not set, you just need to debug through your code to find out why.

Comment: well, it work for the first time with firefox, but when i try it with chrome i get that error. could it be the setCookie does that???

Comment: Oh I see it now in the HTML portion.  You can't use `$this` outside of a class context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i remember it correctly (for zend framework 1.*):

```
// Controller
...
$this->view->user = $this->_helper->model('Users')->fetchRowByFields(array('url' => $referral_url));


// View
echo $this->user->email;
```

Make sure that this `$this->_helper->model('Users')->fetchRowByFields(array('url' => $referral_url))` returns you what you expect. `var_dump` it in controller

Comment: yea, I checked, the first time it getting the user information, then I was trying with another browser then I got a error, could iit be the setCookie in controller does that??

Comment: If error depends on browser, than cookie can be an issue. Depends on what you do with it in js. Can you post that error?

Comment: Select the product to refer your friend Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/refer/application/views/scripts/index/referral-select-product.phtml on line 20 .

Comment: Did you try var_dump in controller to see what is returned  by `$this->_helper->model('Users')->fetchRowByFields(array('url' => $referral_url))` ?

Comment: How is it going to help me with var_dump?

Comment: it actually getting the right information but doesn't print it in the view

Comment: Are you shure that you have `user()` view helper? Try to change it to `$this->user->email` in a view and then try to change controller the way I proposed

Comment: it's getting the infor from database without displaying the errors on every browser. I did what you says changing the $user into $this->view->user and take out the () of the user() in the view. Thanks